# Why can't I set the correct icon for my launcher?

Tags: 12.04, launcher

I created a launcher for Eclipse (STS, actually).  When I double-click it, it starts up Eclipse.  What's annoying is that the icon is the gnome footprint with the left-pointing arrow.  I'd like to set it to use the icon that came with STS.

I edited ~/Desktop/Eclipse.desktop and commented out the Icon line and replaced it with this (where "" is the path to my homedir):

Icon[en_CA]=/apps/springsource/sts-2.9.1.RELEASE/icon.xpm

I restarted the box, but the icon didn't change.  I verified that the path I entered is the path to the xpm file.

Comment: I don't know this for a fact, but is .xpm supported as an icon file for unity? I assumed they were all either png's or svg's.

Comment: xpm works for me.  There are loads of issues with java and unity right now.  Is STS available as an eclipse plug-in?  If so, I would try installing it as a plug-in for eclipse from repo.  It makes most of those problems just go away.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  It never occurred to me that I could click on the icon when viewing the properties dialog to change the icon path.